# Cordova app form doesn't scroll up when Android keyboard is opened

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, cordova

I have simple sign in form in a ReactJS app that I am building for Android using Cordova. However, by opening the keyboard most of the email input and all the password input become completely blocked by it. This is how it currently looks like:

[image]

I know the blank area with the stars looks silly in this example, but it is required to be kept there (it is a placeholder for logo and image).

This could be solved by adding some padding and I simply scroll down, but that generates extra useless space and I am still curious why it's happening in the first place.

This is what my code roughly looks like:

```
class Signin extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='container container-xs text-center'>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} role='form' className='form'>
          <div className='form-group text-left'>
            <label className='control-label'>Email</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              className='form-control'
              value={email}
              onChange={evt => setEmail(evt.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group text-left'>
            <label className='control-label'>Password</label>
              <input
                type='password'
                className='form-control'
                value={password}
                onChange={evt => setPassword(evt.target.value)}
              />
          </div>
          <button>Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there anything that can be done so it automatically scrolls? Keep in mind that this is only happening with the Android app. iOS behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting for Android is set in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  It should be located in your `platforms/android` folder.  In it you should see an `activity` tag that might contain some of the following attributes: `android:configChanges`, `android:label`, `android:launchMode`,`android:windowSoftInputMode`

We want to change the value of the `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

The description of adjustResize is `The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.`

You can read more about the activity element found in AndroidManifest.xml here: [activity element docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)